# Need to convert plain text to code element

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am making a website to display code for a project, and I need a way to read a text file on the server and for every line, I need it to make the text on that line a code element.

Like this:

Input (Example.txt):

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

Output:

```
<code>Line 1</code>
<code>Line 2</code>
<code>Line 3</code>
<code>Line 4</code>
<code>Line 5</code>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string by a newline, then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) through the resulting array and wrap each item inside a `code` element:

```js
const str = `Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5`

const res = str.split("\n").map(e => `<code>${e}</code>`).join('\n')
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thank you! But that only solves the formatting, I still need a way to read it from a file...